# Typescript class unable to implement simple interface with constructor?

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to understand where the problem with this implementation is. I have created a simple test class that implements a very simple interface with a constructor and the Typescript compiler is saying there is a problem.

BaseEntity.ts:

```js
export interface IBaseEntity {
  id: string
  new(_id?: string, _data?: any)
}
```

Test.ts:

```js
class Test implements IBaseEntity {
  id: string
  constructor(_id?: string, _data?: any) {
    this.id = 'MOCK_ID'
  }
}
```

error:

```
Class 'Test' incorrectly implements interface 'IBaseEntity'.
  Type 'Test' provides no match for the signature 'new (_id?: string | undefined, _data?: any): any'.
```

I'm hoping someone can quickly point out where the issue is because it seems to me this is correct. Thanks in advance all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a miss understanding of what `implements` does. `implements` ensures that **the instance type** of the class fulfills the contract specified by the interface. The constructor of the class is not part of the instance type, it is part of the **class type** (the static part of the class).

You need to segregate the static part of the interface form the instance part:

```
export interface IBaseEntity {
  id: string

}

export interface IBaseEntityClass {
    new(_id?: string, _data?: any): IBaseEntity
}


class Test implements IBaseEntity {
  id: string
  constructor(_id?: string, _data?: any) {
    this.id = 'MOCK_ID'
  }
}
let baseEntityClass: IBaseEntityClass = Test; // The class test fulfills the contract of IBaseEntityClass

new baseEntityClass("", {}) // constructing through IBaseEntityClass interface
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=79&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCFMBnYAURQRgE84BvAKDkQBMAuOEmKZAc0aMAvoNCRYiFGiy4CxMpRjUaAYQA2pEg2Ys4SYAHcAFAH0ErAPyduvJHwA0cE60wxMVuJiQ0AlJyKkFFS0woKM2BokWgAqwNyIALZgasAJwChaAQrBdEws5tY8-DrYEEg2AK7YMNCm5h42-I7Oru6cXr7aunAwABYIJAB05nAAvHAA5ACyAPIqANIm+AAiEzoiIinwAEaBisrqmv7yQUq0h1FjcLHcANxwAPQP1714EZo9cfDoFWroCGo1Fo+m8yjwcPAIOg5HschcSIJ9AY4LtsmdVJESEYAETYxz0IQ+R7PUrlHhVJR2Hq9KAQCp8XowtEHTGSVAYHDAIA)

There is currently no way to specify that the class type needs to implement a specific interface, but you would get errors on the assignment `let baseEntityClass: IBaseEntityClass = Test` if `Test` did not have the right constructor.